# Compile time error : Cannot convert 'node*(int)' to 'node*'

Tags: c++

I am getting this error and I am not able to think any good reasons behind it.
Help me out.

I have tried things but cannot get it accepted.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
node* insert(node* root, int data);
node* getnewnode(int data);

int main()
{
    node *root;
    root= NULL;

    root=insert(root,12);
    cout<<root->data;
    root=insert(root,22);
    cout<<root->data;
    root=insert(root,32);
    cout<<root->data;
    root=insert(root,62);
    cout<<root->data;
    root=insert(root,72);
    cout<<root->data;
    root=insert(root,90);
    cout<<root->data;
    root=insert(root,125);
    cout<<root->data;
    root=insert(root,15);
    cout<<root->data;
}

node* getnewnode(int data)
{

    node* newnode = new newnode();
    (*newnode).data=data;
    (*newnode).left=(*newnode).right=NULL;
    return newnode;
}

node* insert(node* root, int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        root = getnewnode();
    else if(data<(*root).data)
        (*root).left=insert((*root).left,data);
    else
        (*root).right=insert((*root).right,data);

    return root;
}
```

I want to know why this error is coming and also what can be done to get it removed.

```
When I compile it, I got this error:

>prog.cpp: In function 'node* insert(node*, int)':  
prog.cpp:48:14: error: cannot convert 'node*(int)' to 'node*' in assignment  
     root = getnewnode;
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell Compile time error?

Comment: `node* newnode = new newnode()` in the `getnewnode()` function is highly suspicious.   Have you described ALL the error messages from the compiler, or just the last one?

Comment: `getnewnode` take one argument, you don't give anything, see my answer to get correct line

Comment: @Peter He write first juste `root = getnewnode;`, I say to him to write with parenthesis, so he edit with just parenthesis... and now he forget parameter

Comment: And also, I suspect that after correction error is different from which one is in your post

Comment: Yeah, okay.  Multiple errors in code, and keeps editing the question when someone points out one of them.   Makes the question useless as answers will be obsolete.   Accordingly, I've voted for closing the question (as, essentially, the problems are careless coding and typos).

Comment: sorry about that @Peter .I did that because I thought it would be good to talk about the real issues apart from that silly mistake of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `root = getnewnode;` try to assign a function to a `int` variable.

To call a function, use parenthesis: `root = getnewnode(data);`

Comment: I have corrected the parenthesis, stil getting the assignation related prblm.

Comment: @karan_13 looking to your edit, you have forget parameter. `getnewnode` take one parameter, so you have to give it a parameter. In your case, this parameter is `data`

Comment: thank you @Garf365 and sorry for that silly mistake.